# Using Vuelidate with Nuxt - keep seeing error even when the condition is met

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuelidate

I'm trying to use Vuelidate with my Nuxt project. So I installed the Vuelidate package, then in the `plugins` folder created `vuelidate.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
```

And defined it in `nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: [
  {src: '~/plugins/directives.js'},
  {src: '~/plugins/vuelidate.js', mode: 'client'}
],
```

BTW, tried it without `mode`, with just strings array - same result.

Now in my component I have the following (Vuetify) text field:

```
<v-text-field
  id='firstName'
  v-model='formData.firstName'
  label='First Name'
  name='firstName'
  prepend-icon='person'
  type='text'
  :error-messages='firstNameErrors'
  @blur='$v.formData.firstName.$touch'
  @input='$v.formData.firstName.$touch'
/>
```

My imports:

```
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
import {
  required,
  minLength,
} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
```

And the rest of my code:

```
export default {
    name: 'AuthForm',
    mixins: [validationMixin],
    validations: {
      formData: {
        firstName: {
          /*required: requiredIf(function() {
            return !this.isLogin
          }),*/
          minLength: minLength(2)
        },
    },
    props: {
      formData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default: () => {}
      }
    },
    computed: {
      firstNameErrors() {
        const errors = []

        if (!this.$v.formData.firstName.$dirty) {
          return errors
        }

        !this.$v.formData.firstName.minLength && errors.push('First name must be at least 2 characters long')

        // !this.$v.formData.firstName.required && errors.push('First name is required')
        return errors
      }
    }
  }
```

So I'm trying to validate that firstName has at least 2 chars. I do see the error message once I start typing, but at 2 and more characters the errors still exist.

I tried to console log `this.$v.formData` in the computed property, but it gets printed once the component is loaded and once I start typing. If I inspect the logged object, I do see that `this.$v.formData.firstName.$model` has more than 2 chars, but I also still see the error, no matter what I tried to do (for example calling `$reset` before calling `$touch` again on input, having `firstNameErrors` as method instead of computed etc...)

The exact same code worked for me in my Vue projects, but this first time I'm working with Nuxt and I'm not sure why this code stopped working. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work if you do `v-model='$v.formData.firstName.$model'`?

Comment: @DavidWeldon Same result...

Comment: Well your nuxt setup is the same as mine, so we can remove that from the list. Other things that could be an issue: you are taking `formData` as a prop, your model is nested, you're using it with `Vuetify`. I'd recommend debugging this by creating a simple form with non-nested component data and an `<input>`. If that works, try adding things back in until it breaks. I get that's a lot of work, but you have a lot of moving pieces here.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Well, I'll try to do that. Will report tomorrow how it goes... Thanks!

Comment: @DavidWeldon Well, apparently I passed the `formData` incorrectly. Once fixed - everything worked just fine! Thanks! That thing drove me crazy here...

Comment: @Igal would help others if you could publish what the fix was in your case

Comment: @Igal any success getting this work? I have the same issue.